# Feature branch is behind dev after squash

Tags: git

Let's say i have two branches: `dev` and `feature`. I've been working on `feature` for some time and merged `dev` to it several times. After the work is done, i merged the latest `dev` to `feature` and started interactive rebase with `git rebase -i my_first_commit_in_feature_branch`. I completed rebase, then i pushed new version of my branch to remote repo and it said that my branch is far behind `dev`. What am i doing wrong and how can i gracefully squash all commits in my branch?

Comment: Is there someone else working on the project? Is your local `dev` branch behind the remote `dev` branch? Could be as simple as you hadn't pulled from the remote `dev` before merging in to `feature`.

Comment: It's far behind `dev`, because by squashing the commits you rewrote the history of changes made to `dev`. You probably need to rebase your `feature` to `dev` now, `git rebase -i dev`. This will put the squashed commit (and its parent) on the top of branch `dev`.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `git rebase -i dev` from the very beginning, instead of rebasing onto `my_first_commit_in_feature_branch`.

Answer (score 0):

Before the rebase it seems that you had a history like below:

```
             dev   
              ↓
A - - B - - - C      
  \    \       \
    D - E - F - G    
                ↑
             feature
```

After the rebase onto `D` you ended up with a rewritten history on the `feature` branch, unrelated to changes made after `A` and to merges:

```
       dev   
        ↓
A - B - C
  \  
    D - H
        ↑
     feature
```

What you need is to put `D` and `H` (or a combined squashed commit) on the top of the changes made in `dev`:

```
$ git rebase dev
```

This should result in the tree as below:

```
       dev   
        ↓
A - B - C
         \
           D - H
               ↑
            feature
```

Now the `feature` branch is ahead of `dev` rather than behind.

Alternatively, you can checkout and go back to `G` and perform a fresh interactive rebase onto `dev`, where you will squash the commits:

```
$ git checkout -b temp G
$ git rebase -i dev
pick D
squash F
```

This way you will end up with:

```
       dev   
        ↓
A - B - C
         \
           I
           ↑
          temp
```